# How to convert aribitrary sized Seq to DataFrame in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `Seq[Seq[String]]` and want to convert it to a Spark dataframe. `toDF()` doesn't provide the expected output which is:

Given: `Seq(Seq("1", "2", "3"))`

Expected:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 1    | 2    | 3    |
```

Using `toDF` crams everything in the first column. So I am converting the `Seq[Seq[String]]` to `Seq[Tuple3[String, String, String]]` and then using `toDF` to get the correct result.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this. It's possible the length of nested Seq might change (but all of them will have the same size) then I will have to change `Tuple3` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Method `spark.createDataFrame` can be used instead of `toDF`, with each internal sequence converted to Row:

```
val data = Seq(Seq("1", "2", "3"))
val columns = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3")
import collection.JavaConverters._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  data.map(Row.fromSeq).asJava,
  StructType(columns.map(name => StructField(name, StringType, true)))
)
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |
+----+----+----+
```